# check if user name and email in database using expressJS

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I am trying to check if an email and an username in a database do already exist. Since I am using mongoose and express.js, I only checked if the username in a database already exists, but I need to check the email and username and return a suitable error message for each one. However, I don't know how to check them. Here are some of code that I wrote so far:

```
User.findOne({
            'username': username
        },
        function(err, user) {

            if (err) {

                console.log('Signup error');
                return done(err);
            }

            //if user found.
            if (user) {

                console.log('Username already exists, username: ' + username);                                                             
                 var err = new Error();
                err.status = 310;
                return done(err);

            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use find() function, this may give you perfect result

```
User.find({ 'username': username,'email':email }, function(err, user) {

        if (err) {

            console.log('Signup error');
            return done(err);
        }

        //if user found.
        if (user.length!=0) {
          if(user[0].username){
            console.log('Username already exists, username: ' + username);                         
             }else{
                console.log('EMAIL already exists, email: ' + email);      
             }                                    
             var err = new Error();
            err.status = 310;
            return done(err);

        }
```

Comment: i need to check if username and email in database then return suitable result for each on 
ex:
if the user enter new user name and existing email i need to tell him the email is  existing and like for username

Comment: edit the code to check username or email address exist , not it will print on log, you can set as you want

Answer (score 9):

First you might want to add this to your schema to ensure all emails are lowercase, so comparison can make sense:

```
email: { type: String, set: toLower }
```

Where toLower is :

```
function toLower (str) {
    return str.toLowerCase();
}
```

Then to lookup MongoDB for docs that matches a username or an email, you can use  [MongoDB `$or` operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/or/)

So the query will be something like this:

```
User.find($or:[{username: username}, {email: email}]);
```

Since you're using mongoose, we can use the [pre middleware](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html), to validate docs before saving

So you're code could be something like this:

```
UserSchema.pre('save', function(next){
  var user = this ;
  User.find($or:[{username: user.username}, {email: user.email}],
            function(err, users){
    if(err) {
      return next(err);
    } else if(users) {
      if (_.find(users , {email: user.email})){
        user.invalidate('email', 'email is already registered'); 
        next( new Error("email is already registered"));
      }
      else if (_.find(users , {username: user.username})){
        user.invalidate('username', 'username is already taken'); 
        next( new Error("username is already taken"));
      }
    }
    else{
      next();
    }   
  })
})
```

This might not cover all the cases, and used [lodash](https://lodash.com) for simplicity and its awesomeness.

Answer (score 0):

You could use index in Schema Mongoose to create unique username and email.
Or you could read more this at here: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/indexes.html